# How to use "butter-es6" package on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, package

Hi I'm trying to learn PERN stack so I'm new in React,

I'm having a problem on how to use butter-es6 on my project. I just want to apply the momentum scrolling on this project

here's what I did so far:

./src/index.js

```
import React from 'react'; import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'; import './style/index.css'; import App from './App'; import Butter from "butter-es6";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => { Butter.init({ wrapperId: "root", wrapperDamper: 0.5, cancelOnTouch: true }) });

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); root.render( <React.StrictMode> <App /> </React.StrictMode> );
```

./src/components/

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react' import './style/App.scss'; import LandingPage from './components/LandingPage'

function App() { const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)return ( <Fragment> <LandingPage loggedIn={loggedIn} /> </Fragment> ); }

export default App;
```

I tried calling `Butter.init()` outside `DOMContentLoaded` event and also tried putting the butter on app.js but not working either, this is my first time asking here so if there is any missing info kindly ask and I'll provide.

If there is alternative for momentum scrolling on React I'll take it also ^_^

thanks in advance ^_^